# Removing the last digit of an inputted integer

Tags: c, for-loop

I was able to reverse the integer inputted using a nested for-loops, but I am unable to remove the last digits when going down through the rows.

(I don't want to use string-to-number, arrays, or functions.)

---

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("enter a number");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    for(int j = 1; j <= (log10(number) + 1); j++) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= (log10(number) + 1); i++) {
            printf("%d   ", (number % ((int)pow(10, i))) / (int)pow(10, i-1));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

My Output: (Inputting 1234)

```
4   3   2   1                                                                                                                        
4   3   2   1                                                                                                                        
4   3   2   1                                                                                                                        
4   3   2   1
```

---

What I want to Output: (Inputting 1234)

```
4   3   2   1   0                                                                                                                        
3   2   1   0                                                                                                                      
2   1   0                                                                                                                     
1   0
0
```

Comment: Okay, so you need to convert to a string, reverse the string and append zero to it? Or should it be the last digit minus 1?  Then you need to print the string starting at increasing indices into the buffer, yes?  But you never create a string, you keep repeating a lot of math and expecting different results.  When you post a homework assignment problem, always post the homework assignment, verbatim, so that we know how to properly answer your question and help you learn the intended lesson.

Comment: I can't use string-to-number, arrays, or functions.

Comment: That's why I'm having a problem.

Comment: [Edit] your post to include the full homework description.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost I just want to understand and learn how to create the output wanted.

Comment: I'm tempted to just write some code ... but I don't want to do your assignment for you.  So let me suggest: 1) It looks like you've mostly got it!  Congratulations!  2) You need to change your outer loop to accomodate the "0".  3) You need to change your inner loop so the range is ONE SHORTER each iteration.

Comment: What is the question I'm asking too complex??

Comment: @paulsm4 Would accomodating my "0", be changing it to j=0?

Comment: No, it's trivial.  You posted a homework assignment without posting the text of the assignment.

Comment: So an example of reversing an integer `b1000`, would be `b0001`.  You see?  You need to be much more specific and when it comes to homework, we need to see the original assignment to be sure you are learning the bits your supposed to be learning.

Comment: This isn't homework, it's practice

Comment: It's not asking for anything other than the output that I put above. And not to use string-to-number, arrays, or functions.

Comment: @paulsm4 Also why won't  number /= 10; to shorten one for each iteration.

Comment: **Never** use `pow` to calculate integers unless you're perfectly content with having `pow(10, 2) == 99`.

Comment: "I can't use ... functions" and accepting an answer employing `log10()` from `<math.h>` is inconsistent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK - since you said this isn't homework (scouts honor ;)):

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void method1(int number) {
  printf("method#1:\n");
  int ndigits = log10(number)+1;
  for(int i=0; i<= ndigits; i++){
    for(int j=0; j <= (ndigits-i); j++){
      //printf ("i= %d, j=%d, numerator= %d, denominator= %d\n",
      //  i, j, (number%((int)pow(10, j+1))), (int)pow(10, j));
      printf("%d   ", (number%((int)pow(10, j+1)))/(int)pow(10, j));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void method2 (int number) {
  printf("method#2:\n");
  /* TBD */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int number;
  printf("enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &number);
  method1(number);
  method2(number);

  return 0;
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
method#1:
4   3   2   1   0
4   3   2   1
4   3   2
4   3
4
```

You'll notice I *haven't* shifted the leftmost digit each iteration.  I'll leave that for you:)

"Method2", should we ever write one, might well include both arrays and strings ;)

And I hope "not using functions" doesn't mean stuffing everything-and-the-kitchen-sink all into your "main()".

Comment: Thanks, I have been doing trial and error for the past hour, and have come out with this

Comment: for(int i=1; i<= (log10(number)+1) - (j-1); i++){
            printf("%d   ", (number%((int)pow(10, i)))/(int)pow(10, i-1));

Comment: It prints a similar output like yours, but I don't know how to  reverse so it's removing the first digits isn't of the last digits once reversed .